# Q&A Posts - The Question

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I'm looking at starting to do Q&A posts here on SuperUser for problems that I encounter, from uncommon problems to common problems. Obviously, the answer will have the most info in the entire post, but how much information do I need to put into the question for Q&A posts?

I understand that it helps if I pretend I'm playing [Jeopardy](https://www.jeopardy.com/), but I can't find any sources that say, specifically, how much info needs to be in the question.

Comment: You should ask a question anyone can answer.  Just because you self-answer does not mean the question itself shouldn't be highly detailed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you feel it can help more people, then it's usually a good idea. Some things to consider, however:

1. Generic instructions need to teach people how to get the answer they need. The answers need to be clear, concise, and contain all the information they would need.
2. Ensure proper information is in the **question**. What logs are needed? What specific instances does this occur in? What has been tried and failed?
3. Ensure the answer is in an Answer section, and **NOT** part of the question.
4. Ensure it has not been asked before. Use the Search function first.
5. If you feel like doing lots, if you are concerned about quality, ask people in Chat. We hang out in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) most of the time, and would be happy to help users in the site.

Comment: I get the answering part, but what about the **question**. What information do I include in the question of my Q&A post?

Comment: @BilfredKerman Emphasized. It's going to change for every question, so if you're not sure, I'd recommend asking in Chat

Comment: Ah yes, I'm blind. Thanks, I'll make sure to use the chat more often.

Comment: Ask the question as if you expect someone else to answer. Its tricky but just enough information to answer, or that you'd someone else to provide works well.

Comment: @BilfredKerman [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not particularly what I meant

Comment: @BilfredKerman - It should be.  If you ask a good question it shouldn't matter you are answering it yourself